# FileNotFoundExpection когда VK возвращает JSON с ошибкой

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Привет, я кидаю запрос на получение токена в **OAuth VK**:

```
JSONObject parsed_url = parseURL("https://oauth.vk.com/token" +
        "?grant_type=password" +
        "&client_id=*********" +
        "&client_secret=*********" +
        "&scope=status,messages" +
        "&username=" + login +
        "&password=" + password
);
```

и если ввести верные данные(логин и пароль) - мне дает `JSON` объект, с которым я работаю, а если я отсылаю не валидные данные, то мне кидает `FileNotFoundExpection`, я бы хотел узнать почему и как от этого избавиться, это не дает мне отсылать `Toast` с сообщением, об неверно введенных данных.

Прочие коды:

```
public JSONObject parseURL(String url_string) throws IOException, JSONException{
    enableStrictMode();
    InputStream is = new URL(url_string).openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String jsonText = readAll(rd);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
    is.close();
    return json;
}


View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.login_button) {
            if (validateData()) {
                try {
                    login();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

login_button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

}

Не поклонник библиотек, вот и не использую их.

Всем добра, если что не так объяснил - простите.

Ошибка:

```
08-28 22:34:53.491 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=*****&client_secret=*****&scope=status,messages&username=ususjsjsj&password=hshshshshs
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at ru.steelskype.app.LoginActivity.parseURL(LoginActivity.java:100)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at ru.steelskype.app.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:80)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at ru.steelskype.app.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:40)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
08-28 22:34:53.498 5615-5615/ru.steelskype.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Username or password is incorrect"} - если вводить с браузера или в PHP

Comment: Это вообще-то Java

Comment: Да, я знаю, но при чем тут это? Я привел это, что бы вы убедились, что в браузере дает нормальную ошибку в JSON.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вариант отправки запроса с помощью HttpUrlConnection как здесь написано https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/. По логу видно что не найден ресурс, может быть как-то некорректно сформирован JSON в случае невалидных данных

Comment: @zuvladimir json нормально работает и парсится в PHP, а тут не хочет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При невалидных данных сервер возвращает статус 401, андроид `com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream` транслирует его в исключение FileNotFoundExpection.
Вы можете обработать исключение в try-catch, либо попробовать использовать другой HTTP Client для достижения Вашей цели.

Comment: Да, я уже так и сделал(try\catch), но мне это кажется глупым костылем.